# How do I enable a remote connection in order to use PostgreSQL?

Tags: linux, postgresql, networking, ambari

I have two vm's on Azure, let's call them test1 and test2.

postgresql-server is installed and running on **test1** (server, where postgres user is), but I want to be able to use psql on **test2** (target).

So far, I've edited the pg_hba.conf, to have the target's IP address in it's list of hosts:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             XX.XXX.XX.XXX/32        trust
```

Where XX.XXX.XX.XXX is the public IP address of my target machine, **test2**.

Then, I edited the postgresql.conf file, to listen to all addresses instead of just localhost:

```
listen_addresses = '*'          # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                                        # comma-separated list of addresses;
                                        # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                                        # (change requires restart)
port = 5432
```

I reload the server on my host server machine to grab the changes:

```
pg_ctl -D /path/to/data/ -l logfile reload
```

As far as I've researched, now I should be able to be on test2, and simply run something like:

```
psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres -p 5432
```

But whenever I do, I get:

```
-bash: psql: command not found
```

What is going on??? Also a test connection to a Hive db (already set up) keeps failing as it could not connect to the database.

Comment: You might be able to connect to your server now, but you will still need the client (in your case ```psql```) on machine ```test2```. Install it and try again

Comment: Thank you! Installing postgresql (not postgresql-server) on test2, allowed me to run ```psql -h test1ip -p 5432```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Islingre commented:

Installing postgresql on the target (test2), allowed me to run:

```
psql -h test1ip -p 5432
```

It worked.